# Transform of basis of vector space $V$ yields new basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $ v= \{v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{n} \} $ be a basis of vector space $ \ V $. 
>   Prove that $ \bar v=\{\bar v_1,\bar v_2,\dots,\bar v_n\}$ is also a basis of $ V$, where each ${\bar v_{k}}$ is a linear combination of $ {v_{1}} , \dots, {v_{k}} $ , with a nonzero coefficient of $ v_{k}$.

(This means we can replace any basis vector with any linear combination of that vector with the 'preceding' basis vectors. ).

**Answer:** 
Let ${\bar v_{k}}=c_{1} v_{1}+c_{2}v_{2}+\dots+c_{k}{v_{k}}+\dots+c_{n}v_{n} $ , $ c_{k} \neq 0$.

Or, $ v_{k}=\frac{1}{c_{k}} {\bar v_{k}}-\frac{c_{1}}{c_{k}}{v_{1}}-\dots-\frac{1}{c_{k}}{v_{n}}$, since $c_{k} \neq 0$.

Is this correct, so far? How to complete this attempt?

Comment: The hypothesis that every $\bar v_k$ is a linear combination of $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_k$, does **not** translate as $\bar v_k=c_{1} v_{1}+c_{2}v_{2}+\dots+c_{k}v_k+\dots+c_{n}v_{n}$ with $ c_{k} \neq 0$. You might want to start by revising this step.

Comment: @mabmath: If you're still stuck, try to write out an argument for $n = 3$ (or even $n = 2$). That should help clarify where your argument goes off the rails (cf. Did's comment).

Comment: @mabmath Since my first comment to you, you saw fit to accept (and, possibly, to upvote) the (wrong) post below. Is this meant as some kind of test of the system?

Comment: mabmath You haven't started an attempt, so no attempt can be completed. You posted a problem  statement, and as your attempt, you simply restated the premise of the problem stated.  Poor excuse if you think that constitutes an attempt!

Comment: I already has proved that theorem . I posted a logical attempt which explains the main reason that $ a_k \neq 0 \ \ implies \ a_k^{-1} \ exists $

Comment: It is not enough to show that $a_k^{-1}$ exists.  The statement you are trying to prove is true as quoted at the top of your post, but is not true if interpreted the way you have done later in the post.  In particular, your equation ${\bar v_{k}}=c_{1} v_{1}+c_{2}v_{2}+\dots+c_{k}{v_{k}}+\dots+c_{n}v_{n}$ with $c_k\ne0$ allows $\bar v_1=\bar v_2=\ldots=\bar v_n=v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n$.  For every $k$ we have that the coefficient of $v_k$ in $\bar v_k$ is $1$, and therefore not $0$.  But the $\bar v_k$ are identical, and therefore certainly not linearly independent.

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the regularity of upper triangular matrices?

Answer (score 2):

We have that the vectors $\bar v$ are given by linear combination

$$
  \bar v_i = \sum_{j=1}^{i} c_{ji}v_j,
$$
so

\begin{eqnarray}
  \bar v_1 &=& c_{11}v_1\\
  \bar v_2 &=& c_{12}v_1+c_{22}v_2\\
  &\vdots& \\
\bar v_n &=& c_{1n}v_1+\ldots +c_{nn}v_n.\\
\end{eqnarray}

Let us define $$C= \begin{pmatrix} c_{11} & c_{12} & \ldots & c_{1n}\\
                                  0& c_{22} & \ldots &c_{2n} \\
                                  \vdots &\vdots  &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 &0&0&c_{nn}
  \end{pmatrix},$$

note that $$Ce_i=\bar v_i,$$
where the components $(e_i)_j=\delta_{ij}$ and $\bar v_i$ is given in the basis $v$.

If we suppose* that $C^{-1}$ exists, then 
$$e_i = C^{-1}\bar v_i.$$ This means that $C$ is the matrix that governs  the change of coordinates of $\bar v$ under the change of basis from $v'$ to $v$.
In this way $(e_i)_j = \delta_{ij}$ are the components of $\bar v_i$ in the basis $v'$, but it's only possible to have such components (standard components) if $v' =\bar v$.

So, indeed, as long as $$ c_{ii} \neq 0 \text{ for all } i,$$
$\bar v$ is a basis for V.

*What are the conditions necessary to $C^{-1}$ exist? From Laplace's Expansion Theorem is easy to prove that
$$\textrm{det } C = c_{11}c_{22} \cdots c_{nn}= \text{ product of the elements of the diagonal,}$$
since $C^{-1}$ exists iff $C$ is non singular:

$$ c_{11}c_{22} \cdots c_{nn}\neq 0 \Rightarrow c_{ii} \neq 0 \text{ for all } i.$$